# How to get input text from WKInterfaceTextField in watchOS?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have one textfield like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tfAmount: WKInterfaceTextField!
```

and I want the input text from **tfAmount** on button Action.
So, How can I get?

Comment: You would need to connect an action to the text field and store the text in a property that you can access from your button action. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacetextfield?language=objc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To receive the text entered by the user, connect the text field in the storyboard to an action method defined in your interface controller.

Obj-C

```
- (IBAction)textFieldAction:(NSString*) value
```

Swift

```
@IBAction func textFieldAction(_ value: NSString?)
```

WatchKit calls the action method after the user dismisses the text input controller. The value parameter contains the string entered by the user. If the user cancels the text input controller, the value is nil.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacetextfield?language=swift

Answer (score 1):

To receive the text entered by the user, connect the text field in the storyboard to an action method defined in your interface controller.

```
var userData = ""

//weak connection
@IBOutlet weak var textField: WKInterfaceTextField!

//action connection
@IBAction func textFieldAction(_ value: NSString?) {
    userData = value! as String
}
```